# How to access all userdata via session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please I have created a login and passed email and id and I can access them in my view. But I am unable to access other userdata like name, phone, etc. Am only able to access email, id and session id. Your help is appreciated.

here is my model

```
public function login($email, $password){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('passwd', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->row()->uid;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

here is my controller

```
public function login(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');


if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

    echo validation_errors('<p class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">');
}
else{

        //Get post data
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $enc_pwd = sha1($password);
        $id = $this->User_model->login($email, $enc_pwd);

        if($id){
            $userdata = array(
                'id'        =>  $id,
                'email'     =>  $email,
                'logged_in' =>  TRUE
                );


            //Set session data
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);


            //Redirect to Users page
            redirect('site/dashboard');
        }
        else{
            //Create Error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Login credentials are incorrect');


            //Redirect to Users page
            redirect('site/login');
        }

        //Add activity
        //$this->Activity_model->add($data);            
    }

    //Load the login template
    $this->load->view('public/login');

}
```

Comment: `id, email, logged_in` are the only session variables you are setting.

Comment: I added other variables and when I tried getting them from the view, it's null. Could you please suggest to me a way to set the other variables?

Comment: add additional indexes to your `$userdata`. You can then access `$this->session->userdata('logged_in')[1] etc...`

Comment: some thing like this? 
 `$userdata = array(
                'id'        =>  $id,
                'email'     =>  $email,
                'name'    => $name,
                'logged_in' =>  TRUE
                );`
It didn't work.

Comment: Side note:Make sure you 'login' again so the variables can 'set' them into the session.

Comment: @Duikboot I did that after adding the variables and it did return the following variables with values id, $email. The $name variable returned empty.

Comment: If I manually set the variable like so `$name => 'My name'` it returns a value. Now the big part s fetching the details of the person logged in from the database. I've tried a couple of ways but no way. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your sesssion in the Model

Refer the code below.Check how to set other variables in session

**Model**

```
function login($email, $password)
{
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $this -> db -> from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('passwd', $password);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this -> db -> get();  
    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
        'email'=>  $email,
        'id' => $row->id,
        'name' => $row->name,
        'phone' => $row->phone,
        'logged_in' =>  TRUE 
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Anywhere you can call that session variable.

Comment: So how do I call a variable in the view using this model function? Because `$row->name` returns undefined variable error.

Comment: Thanks @robins, I was able to aadjust my controller to fit the change in model. And everything is fine now. Codeigniter (programming generally) can be strange.